# Siri reports my correct birthday, but then uses wrong date when asked how many days until my birthday

Tags: iphone, siri

When I say to Siri "When is my Birthday", the response is May 20th, which is correct.

However, when I say "How many days until my birthday" the response uses September 16th as the birthday. How do I fix this?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem on my iPhone 4S running iOS 6.0. I say "How many days until my birthday" and the answer from Wolfram Alpha uses September 16, 2013 as my birthday (which it is not).

Comment: It's obviously because the world ends soon.

Comment: 2015, issue still happening :/

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a bug that either Apple or Wolfram Alpha will have to fix. I reported the bug at http://bugreport.apple.com/ .